# StackWalk64 seems to work but SymFromAddr returns bogus names

Tags: winapi, dbghelp

I implemented the following function to get the current stack on windows:

```
struct StackFrame
{
    DWORD64 address;
    std::string name;
    std::string module;
};

std::vector<StackFrame> GetStackTrace()
{
    DWORD  machine = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;
    HANDLE process = GetCurrentProcess();
    HANDLE thread  = GetCurrentThread();

    STACKFRAME64 frame   = {};
    CONTEXT      context = {};

    if (SymInitialize(process, NULL, TRUE) == FALSE)
    {
        DBG_TRACE(__FUNCTION__ ": Failed to call SymInitialize.");
        return std::vector<StackFrame>(); 
    }

    context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
    RtlCaptureContext(&context);

    #ifdef _M_IX86
        machine                 = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386;
        frame.AddrPC.Offset     = context.Eip;
        frame.AddrPC.Mode       = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrFrame.Offset  = context.Ebp;
        frame.AddrFrame.Mode    = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrStack.Offset  = context.Esp;
        frame.AddrStack.Mode    = AddrModeFlat;
    #elif _M_X64
        machine                 = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64;
        frame.AddrPC.Offset     = context.Rip;
        frame.AddrPC.Mode       = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrFrame.Offset  = context.Rsp;
        frame.AddrFrame.Mode    = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrStack.Offset  = context.Rsp;
        frame.AddrStack.Mode    = AddrModeFlat;
    #elif _M_IA64
        machine                 = IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_IA64;
        frame.AddrPC.Offset     = context.StIIP;
        frame.AddrPC.Mode       = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrFrame.Offset  = context.IntSp;
        frame.AddrFrame.Mode    = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrBStore.Offset = context.RsBSP;
        frame.AddrBStore.Mode   = AddrModeFlat;
        frame.AddrStack.Offset  = context.IntSp;
        frame.AddrStack.Mode    = AddrModeFlat;
    #else
    #error "This platform is not supported."
    #endif

    std::vector<StackFrame> frames;
    while (StackWalk64(machine, process, thread, &frame, &context , NULL, SymFunctionTableAccess64, SymGetModuleBase64, NULL))
    {
        StackFrame f;
        f.address = frame.AddrPC.Offset;

        DWORD64 moduleBase = SymGetModuleBase64(process, frame.AddrPC.Offset);

        char moduelBuff[MAX_PATH];            
        if (moduleBase && GetModuleFileNameA((HINSTANCE)moduleBase, moduelBuff, MAX_PATH))
        {
            f.module = basename(moduelBuff);
        }
        else
        {
            f.module = "Unknown Module";
        }

        DWORD64 offset = 0;
        char symbolBuff[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)];   
        PSYMBOL_INFO symbol = (PSYMBOL_INFO)symbolBuff;

        symbol->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO);
        symbol->MaxNameLen   = MAX_SYM_NAME;

        if (SymFromAddr(process, frame.AddrPC.Offset, &offset, symbol))
        {
            f.name = symbol->Name;
        }
        else
        {
            DWORD error = GetLastError();
            DBG_TRACE(__FUNCTION__ ": Failed to resolve address 0x%X: %u\n", frame.AddrPC.Offset, error);
            f.name = "Unknown Function";
        }

        frames.push_back(f);
    }

    SymCleanup(process);

    return frames;
}
```

The stack walk appears to work as expected, I get about as many frames as in the debugger. Also the `SymGetModuleBase64` and `GetModuleFileName` work properly to resolve module names.

But the call to `SymFromAddr` always gives me the same function for one module. Each address is different and testing some address, they appear correct.

The PDBs are generated with /Zi and /DEBUG.

Any idea what I can do to get it to work properly?

Comment: what are the names you are getting? are they overrides perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

The code is ok and successfully runs form years now. See [dbg.h](https://github.com/rioki/rex/blob/master/rex/dbg.h#L100) for a functioning implementation.

It turned out the environment was just borked. Some module was messing the around in weird ways. In other contexts the code has runs flawlessly for years now.